# Python subprocess.popen returns empty string

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess
cd=['sudo','./interface','-a','</tmp/vol.js']
p = subprocess.Popen(cd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Above code returns null but when I run same same command i.e `sudo ./interface -a </tmp/vol.js` works totally fine

Answer (score 1):

You are using *shell-specific redirection syntax* (`</tmp/vol.js`) but `subprocess.Popen()` doesn't run your command in a shell.

You'd need to either run the command in a shell (pass in a *string*, not a list, and set `shell=True`), or open `vol.js` yourself and write that to the process through the `stdin` pipe you opened:

```
import subprocess
command = ('sudo', './interface', '-a')
with open('/tmp/vol.js') as input_stream:
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=input_stream)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Note that I passed in the open `vol.js` file object as the input stream here.

Comment: p = subprocess.Popen("sudo ./interface -a </tmp/vol.js", stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell= True) still returns nothing :/

Comment: @GouthamHM: why are you setting `stdin` to a pipe in that case? You are providing input through a `<` redirect, so giving additional input to the shell is probably causing something to wait.

Comment: @GouthamHM: also, I am assuming you have set up `sudo` to not ask for a password for this command.

Comment: @martin I tried the code you mentioned it still returns nothing !

Comment: @GouthamHM: Is `./interface` in your current working directory? Is there any output in `stdout` or `stderr` that indicates an error message?

Comment: @martin ya  ./interface is of current directory stderr and stdout prints nothing

Comment: You haven't really defined what 'works totally fine' *means* here, by the way. Perhaps the `./interface` script only produces output if it is connected to a terminal? What is the goal of the `./interface` script? Can it be made to produce debugging output to tell you what might have gone wrong?

Comment: @martin thanks a lot! my vol.js had some syntax error input_stream was really hel;pful :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this.

```
import subprocess
cd = ['sudo','./interface','-a','</tmp/vol.js']
cd_cmd = " ".join(cd)
o, e = subprocess.Popen(cd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

The output is stored in variable "o" and stderr in "e"